# Can't call custom swift init from objective-c class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a custom class with a custom init written in swift. I need to call that init from an Objective-C class.

**Swift**

```
@objc public class MyClass: NSObject {

    public init(configuration config: Data)
    {
        super.init()
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[MyClass alloc] initWithConfiguration:CONFIG];
```

But when I call the init from Objective-C the compiler complains that

> No visible @interface for 'MyClass' declares the selector
> 'initWithConfiguration:'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please prove that you imported the generated header into your Objective-c _.m_ file.

Comment: @matt looking at the generated header file and it appears as the init function isn't listed in the interface. That would explain why my obj-c code can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `@objc` attribute to initializers too. Like this:

```
@objc public init(configuration config: Data)
{
    super.init()
    // Do Stuff
}
```

And after this, don't forget to re-build (CMD+B), otherwise Xcode will stupidly emit an error.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it.

Comment: @cHorse1981 Yes, it is. I tried it and I see `- (nonnull instancetype)initWithConfiguration:(NSData * _Nonnull)config OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;` in the generated header.

Comment: @matt I tried it and it didn't show up in the generated header. There's something else going on (possibly in addition to this).

Comment: @cHorse1981 Well, I could show you what I did in an answer, but that would duplicate this answer so there's no point. If MyClass is marked `@objc` and `init(configuration:)` is marked `@objc` you _will_ see that class and that initializer declared in the _-Swift.h_ generated header. And if Objective-C imports that header, it _will_ see those declarations. Try clearing out your derived data and restarting your machine, then build again and look at the generated interface file again.

Comment: @matt you can insist that this will work all you want but obviously there's something else afoot. I've followed your advice and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @cHorse1981 Would you like me to provide a demo app?

Comment: @matt I'm not saying your wrong. I'm saying your suggestions aren't working. I don't care if you have a working example. Once again, I've followed your advice, It's not working for me, something else is going on.

Comment: @cHorse1981 But your question doesn't include "something else". What I'd like to do is demonstrate that this is the right answer, all other things being equal, to the question you actually asked. (I have no idea what the "other things" could possibly be. That matter appears quite straightforward to me.)

Comment: @cHorse1981 You can create a new minimum demo to try out. Perhaps you will be able to narrow down the issue enough.

Comment: @BenjaminWen turns out there was some sort of bug in Xcode 11.0 that was causing the problem.